# How to get the object property values for the specified individual?

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl, protege, owl-api

I have an ontology, created using Protegé 4.3.0, and I would use the OWL-API in order to get the object property values (ie. a set of `OWLNamedIndividual` objects) for the specified individual and object property expression.

```
Set<OWLNamedIndividual> values = reasoner.getObjectPropertyValues(individual, hasPart).getFlattened();
```

Unfortunately the above instruction return no items, since in my ontology the association between individuals is via some sub object properties of `hasPart` object property.

**UPDATE**: In the last few hours I had found the following solution in order to get the sub object properties related to a specified `OWLNamedIndividual`.

```
private Set<OWLObjectProperty> getRelatedSubObjectProperties(OWLNamedIndividual individual) {
    HashSet<OWLObjectProperty> relatedObjectProperties = new HashSet<>();

    HashSet<OWLObjectPropertyExpression> subProperties = new HashSet<>();
    subProperties.addAll(hasPart.getSubProperties(ontology));

    Set<OWLClass> types = reasoner.getTypes(individual, true).getFlattened();

    for (OWLObjectPropertyExpression property : subProperties) {
        Set<OWLClassExpression> domains = property.getDomains(ontology);
        for (OWLClassExpression domain : domains) {
            if (types.contains(domain.asOWLClass())) {
                relatedObjectProperties.add(property.asOWLObjectProperty());
            }
        }
    }

    return relatedObjectProperties;
}
```

Then I would get the object property values as follows:

```
for (OWLObjectProperty property : getRelatedSubObjectProperties(individual)) {
    Set<OWLNamedIndividual> values = reasoner.getObjectPropertyValues(individual, property).getFlattened();
    if (values != null) {
        for (OWLNamedIndividual value : values) {
            // a value associated to the individual
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry maybe this is very obvious, but just for my information, why is it you are you calling the `getObjectPropertyValues()` method on the reasoner and not on the particular `OWLNamedIndividual`?

Comment: Calling the method on the individual does not use the reasoner to answer, so its results might be incomplete.

Comment: @KunalKhaladkar: Your solution actually looks better: calling `getObjectPropertyValues()` method on the particular `OWLNamedIndividual` returns a `Map<OWLObjectPropertyExpression, Set<OWLIndividual>>`, so I should check what keys are sub object property of `hasPart`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `getObjectPropertyValues()` does not explicitly state that subproperties will be taken into account, so the behaviour here might be reasoner dependent. Which reasoner are you using?

One workaround is to get all subproperties of the property you're using and loop through all of them, so that you'll obtain all results.

Comment: I updated my question, adding the solution I implemented to find all the sub object properties related to the specified `OWLNamedIndividual` object.

Comment: I'm using the structural reasoner, but I'm aware that it does not do inferences, but uses the asserted axioms in the ontology. However I was thinking that a better solution might be that proposed by _KunalKhaladkar_, ie. invoking the `getObjectPropertyValues()` on the particular `OWLNamedIndividual`: this method returns a `Map<OWLObjectPropertyExpression, Set<OWLIndividual>>`, so I should check what keys are sub object property of `hasPart`...

Comment: Using the structural reasoner will definitely not return uses of subproperties. If you're limiting yourself to that reasoner, @KunalKhaladkar solution is equivalent.