# Get "Individual Usages" in OWL API

Tags: java, protege, owl-api

I am a beginner at OWL API so please forgive me if this is a basic thing.

I have a class named Flammability which has 5 instances of Flammability Levels from 0 to 4 (e.g. "Flammability Level: 0"). I want to get the individuals (chemicals) that "hasFlammabilityLevel" of say, "Flammability Level: 0" and put them in a HashMap, "emergencyChemicalsMap". I have been searching and tried many methods such as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548780/how-to-get-the-object-property-values-for-the-specified-individual#32549774) and [this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695956/retrieve-owl-individuals-with-same-object-properties-using-owl-api-4-0) but none of them work and returns nothing.

This is the code I currently have which is supposed to get the Flammability Level of each individual as my trial but it doesn't really return anything and have no idea what to do anymore:

```
OWLClass emergencyChemicals = null;
        for (OWLClass owlClass : classes) {
            String x = owlClass.getIRI().toString();
            x = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
            if (x.equals("ProductName")) {
                emergencyChemicals = owlClass;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (emergencyChemicals != null)
            for (OWLNamedIndividual instances : reasoner.getInstances(emergencyChemicals,false).getFlattened()) {
                OWLObjectProperty hasFlammabilityLevel = df.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create("#hasFlammabilityLevel"));
                OWLClassExpression flammabilityOfI = df.getOWLObjectHasValue(hasFlammabilityLevel, instances);
                for (OWLNamedIndividual flammability : reasoner.getInstances(flammabilityOfI, false).getFlattened()) {
                    String label = flammability.getIRI().getFragment();
                    emergencyChemicalMap.put(label, instances);
                }
            }
```

Is there a way to do this such that it returns individuals from the class "ProductName" that "hasFlammabilityLevel" of "Flammability Level: 0"? Answers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you creating the reasoner? Which reasoner are you using?

Comment: Also, there's another issue with the code: `df.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create("#hasFlammabilityLevel"));`

That is not the full IRI of the property, and will not match the property in your ontology. You need to use the full IRI for this code to work.